# initializing struct while using auto causes a copy in VS 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

In the following code the line that creates `nested` object prints only "constructor" [with gcc](http://ideone.com/Yu2NzE), but not with VS 2013:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test {
    test()            { cout << "constructor" << endl; }
    test(const test&) { cout << "copy constructor" << endl; }
    test(test&&)      { cout << "move constructor" << endl; }
    ~test()           { cout << "destructor" << endl; }
};

struct nested {
    test t;
//    nested() {}
};

auto main() -> int {
    // prints "constructor", "copy constructor" and "destructor"
    auto n = nested{};
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
constructor
copy constructor
destructor

destructor
```

So I guess what happening here is that a temporary object gets copied into `n`. There is no compiler-generated move constructor, so that's why it's not a move.

I'd like to know if this is a bug or an acceptable behaviour? And why adding a default constructor prevents a copy here?

Comment: Mine (clang) prints `destructor` as well (and I find it odd yours doesn't according to your opening sentence).

Comment: @WhozCraig I phrased it wrong. Of course it prints "destructor" too, but that is expected. I meant the output that `auto n = nested{}` line produce.

Comment: It would appear then that gcc is eliding the copy, and MS is not (nor do they *have* to). Stupid as this sounds, is the same behavior the case when you use `nested n = nested{};` ? (if it isn't the same, I officially raise by MS-sucks bar to a whole new level).

Comment: @WhozCraig It's the same, so it's not `auto`'s fault. Replacing `{}` with `()` helps though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not `auto` that's the problem; the following will exhibit the same:

```
nested n = nested{};
```

The temporary is being direct-initialized with `{}`, and then `n` is being copy-initialized with that, because `test` is a class-type (in this case, has user-defined constructor).

An implementation is *permitted* to directly initialize the ultimate target (`n`), but isn't *obligated* to, so either is legal.

Lots (really, **lots**) of details in 8.5 and 8.5.1 of the Standard.

Comment: `because test is a class-type (in this case, has user-defined constructor)`, hmm, but `nested` doesn't have any?..

Comment: Indeed - but it's init-list (for aggregates) is shorter than it's member-list, so the member gets direct-initialized with the equivalent of `test{}`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a failure of MSVC to do copy elision (I'd guess related to the brace-init-constructor). It's perfectly legal both ways.

Comment: But very sad for MSVC users.

Comment: @SebastianRedl in their defense, VS2013 is not RTM yet and it is related to a "new" feature (if it is not the `auto` messing things up of course)...

Comment: True. All the more reason to submit a bug report.

Comment: @rubenvb Indeed, it's not the `auto`. Replacing `{}` with `()` prevents copy.

Comment: Yay for my supernatural abilities! Where are those upvotes?! `:-P`